Necesito ayuda con esta frase
¿Qué quiere decir esta frase?
"El alfabeto latino es ampliamente el alfabeto más usado del mundo."
Significa lo mismo que "El alfabeto latino es el alfabeto más ampliamente usado del mundo."
¿Se refiere a la extensión geografica del alfabeto latino o algo más?

La oración está mal construida, considero que solo el autor podría aclarar qué es lo que quiso decir. Sin embargo, si cambias de lugar la palabra ampliamente, como has hecho, tiene sentido. Solo podemos suponer que eso fue lo que quiso decir el autor, pero nadie podría decirlo con total autoridad más que él/ella.

@jachguate No hay nada que esté mal en esa oración. Ambas están bien, aunque es raro ese uso de ‘ampliamente’.

En mi opinión, está mal construida. Sería diferente si dijera: "ampliamente el más usado", pero redundar en decir alfabeto, por lo menos, la "enrarece", y diría que gramaticalmente, si no es totalmente incorrecta, está en un área gris... pero correcta no es.

Para mí, el problema es la repetición de ‘alfabeto’, lo que hace a la frase algo cacofónica. Después, semánticamente ese ampliamente parece calcado. Lo más usual es usar por lejos, o habría que buscar otro adverbio adecuado, quizá exorbitantemente. Pero no creo que la cosa vaya por el orden de las palabras.

El adverbio "ampliamente" se usa para intensificar algunos participios en función de adjetivo: ampliamente usado, ampliamente conocido, ampliamente sabido, ampliamente detallado.
La oración:

El alfabeto latino es ampliamente el alfabeto más usado del mundo

no es una buena oración en español. Para que un adverbio pueda colocarse en esa posición, debería poder ubicarse también al inicio o al final de la oración, porque sería un adverbio extraoracional por el cual el hablante califica todo lo que está diciendo, y NO decimos:
(?) Ampliamente, el alfabeto latino es el alfabeto más usado del mundo.
(?) El alfabeto latino es el alfabeto más usado del mundo, ampliamente.
(Solo la segunda oración de arriba sería aceptable en lengua oral, para enfatizar algo que ya se dijo, algo así como un intensificador tardío.)
Comparemos con estas oraciones donde el adverbio en -mente funciona perfectamente bien en cualquier posición:

El alfabeto latino es(,) indudablemente(,) el alfabeto más usado del mundo.

Indudablemente, el alfabeto latino es el alfabeto más usado del mundo.

El alfabeto latino es el alfabeto más usado del mundo, indudablemente.


Además, "más" modifica a "ampliamente", no a "usado". La combinación léxica es "ampliamente usado", y "más" modifica a esa unidad léxica. Por lo tanto, la ubicación correcta de "ampliamente" es delante del participio:

El alfabeto latino es el alfabeto más ampliamente usado del mundo.


No creo que sea una mala oración. Aquí, ampliamente significa por una amplia diferencia. Si acaso, faltan comas alrededor de ampliamente, como en tu ejemplo con indudablemente.

This spanish sentence is grammatically correct. It should be translated as ‘The Latin alphabet is by far the most widely used alphabet in the world.'

The Spanish sounds like literal translation from English.

Si te refieres al alfabeto latino que se utiliza en español, inglés y otros idiomas, la respuesta es sí.
El alfabeto latino es el más utilizado, ya que lo emplea casi el 70 por ciento de la población mundial.
Está formado por 26 letras y es la base del Alfabeto Fonético Internacional, que se utiliza para relacionar la fonética de todos los idiomas.
